# Take my data from my computer and Verify that data is not stolen

Tags: python, django

As a Python programmer recently I received a small project to edit and add some functions. (the project is Python/Django)
But while I was working on it, I noticed something unusual, which is the presence of some python libraries(hashlib and others), which can take my data(Gmail accounts, passwords, chrome bookmarks . . .) from the computer.
This Script is an example from the code.

```
import hashlib
import logging

import re
import pandas as pd

from file import reader

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def load_data(user_id, project_id, columns: dict):
    group_files = {}
    df = pd.DataFrame(None)
    for id_, column in columns.items():
        group = column['group']
        if group not in group_files:
            df_file = reader.load_file(user_id, project_id, group)

            group_files[group] = df_file

        if group_files[group] is not None:
            if column['content'] in group_files[group].columns:
                df[column['content']] = group_files[group][column['content']]

    return df


def get_hash(string: str):
    return hashlib.md5(string.encode()).hexdigest()[:5]
```

**My question is: How can I know if they are taking my data from the computer or not?**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would recommend combing through all the custom function to check that there isn't any logging software that would be running maliciously. If not, then you should be ok.

Comment: why you think `hashlib` means malware?

Comment: hashlib is a python module https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html  not a malware

Comment: @hardy, what line of the above snippet you are concerned about?

Comment: thank you guys for your answer.

i just want to mention here for the code i can't put it all here because it's a huge Django program and a lot of applications, and made by a senior developer. and because of that, i put a small script.

Comment: yes i know hash lib a python module, but you can extract data from any web server or bookmarks(favorites in google chrome).

Comment: @Hardy, Python `hashlib` hashing function takes variable length of bytes and converts it into a fixed length sequence. This is a one way function.

Comment: @NKSM
so, does this mean that I shouldn't have to worry about my data?